# UTC to GPS time for finding TOW in Simulink

Tags: matlab, gps, simulink, gps-time

for my project, I need to calculate TOW (Time of week) in Simulink. I know this can be achieved through conversion of UTC time to GPS time.

I have written a simple m-file in Matlab which does the action for me in Matlab as follow:

```
date_gps_int = 10000*y + 100*m + d
date_gps_str = int2str(date_gps_int)
date_gps_str_to_serial = datenum(date_gps_str,'yyyymmdd')
date_str_format = datestr(date_gps_str_to_serial,'dd-mmmm-yyyy')
Num_Days = daysact('06-jan-1980',date_str_format)
Num_Weeks = Num_Days/7
TOW = Num_Weeks - 1024
```

My first intention was to use this as a function in simulink. But apparently because of  'datenum' and 'datestr' it is not possible, since simulink does not handle strings.

Now I am wondering if anyone can help me with this issue. Is there any way to calculate TOW from the UTC date in Matlab without using those predefined functions?

I also tried to write an algorithm for calculating number of days since '6 January 1980' and then calculating number of weeks by dividing that by 7. But since I am not very familiar with leap year calculation and I don't really know the formula for these kinds of calculations, my result differs from real TOW.

I would appreciate if anybody can help me on this.

Comment: If you do not need code generation you can make an external function, call it extrinsic and call it from a MATLAB Function block in Simulink.

Comment: Not really answering, but you should check if you really need to take care about leap seconds. Often time conversions are done just for reporting (to human), so you may discard an extra second. If you need need precise time differences, you may need a good conversion and so look the real answers.

Answer (score 1):

There are three formats handled by Matlab for time: formatted date strings - what `datestr` outputs -, serial date - scalar double, what `datenum` outputs - and **date vectors** (see [`datevec`](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datevec.html)). Conversion functions work with these three, and the most convenient way to convert individual variables (year, month, etc) to a date is to build a date vector `[yyyy mm dd HH MM SS]`.

```
date_gps_str_to_serial = datenum([y m d 0 0 0]); % midnight on day y-m-d
date_Jan_6_1980 = datenum([1980 01 06 0 0 0]);   % midnight on Jan 6th, 1980
Num_Days = date_gps_str_to_serial - date_Jan_6_1980;
```

Now, beware of [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second)...

GPS time is computed form the time elapsed since Jan 6th 1980. Take the number of seconds elapsed since that day, as measured by the satellites' atomic clocks, divide by (24*3600) to get a number of days, the remainder is the time of the day (in seconds since midnight).

But, once in a while, the *International Earth Rotation and Reference Systems Service* will decide that a day will last one second longer to accommodate for the slowing of Earth rotation. It may happen twice a year, on June 30th or December 31st. The calculation of GPS time is wrong, because it does not take into account that some days last 86401 seconds (so dividing by 24*3600 does not work) and will advance by 1 second with respect to UTC each time this happens. There has been 18 such days since Jan 6th 1980, so one should subtract **18 seconds** from GPS time to find UTC time. The next time a leap second may be added is June 2019.